# How to change WM theme in Xubuntu 15.10 + compiz?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, compiz, xfce

Gnome-tweak-tool seems to have deleted the feature to change the window decoration theme.

[gnome-tweak tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCHon.png)